# PhoneGap push plugin not registering on ioS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

I am using the following plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push with my phonegap application. Am not getting anything on the ioS version on the registration event. On Android it works 100%. I request assistance to see if I am missing anything. The code is below. I have the certificates and have enabled push services. I created a distribution certificate and  the application is on the apple store. Basically on startup I have a self-calling function and send the registration via http to our server, we are not getting anything from ioS. We used phonegapbuild to build the ioS version and upload via macincloud.com. I have read a few posts here but none solves my issue.

```
<gap:plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" source="npm" >
   <param name="SENDER_ID" value="15971xxxxxxx" />
</gap:plugin>
```

My environment is 
Windows 10
Cordova -v 6.0.0
phonegap -v 5.5.0
push plugin -v 1.5.3

And here is the code

```
(function() {
'use strict';
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    var samplePushApp = angular.module('samplePushApp');
    samplePushApp.factory('deviceService', deviceService);

    deviceService.$inject = ['$http', '$q',  '$cordovaDevice', 'messagesSqlLiteService'];

    function deviceService($http, $q,  $cordovaDevice, messagesSqlLiteService) {
            var url = 'http://example.com/api/device/';
            console.log("PushNotification Registration");
            var push = PushNotification.init({ 
                "android": {"senderID": "15971xxxxxxx"},
                "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, 
                "windows": {} } );

            push.on('registration', function(data) {
                console.log(data.registrationId);
                console.log("data.registrationId");
                var model = $cordovaDevice.getModel();
                var platform = $cordovaDevice.getPlatform();
                var uuID =  $cordovaDevice.getUUID();
                var version = $cordovaDevice.getVersion();
                var data = { "model": model, "platform": platform, "registrationId": data.registrationId, "DeviceId": uuID , "version ": version  };
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                $http.post(
                    url,
                    JSON.stringify(data),
                    {
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'Accept': 'application/json'
                        }
                    }
                ).success(function() {
                    console.log("Device Info submitted");
                }).error(function(data, status) {
                    console.error('Device Info error', status, data);
                });
            });

            push.on('notification', function(data) {
                navigator.notification.alert(data.title+" Message: " + data.message, function(){}, "", "");
                messagesSqlLiteService.insert(data);
                location.href = '#messages';
            });

            push.on('error', function(e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            });
    }

    // create an injector
    var $injector = angular.injector(['samplePushApp']);
    $injector.invoke(deviceService);


}
})();
```

SOLVED

As an update. It turns out that there was nothing wrong with the code. There were two main issues.

I eventually borrowed a mac(from macincloud) and built the project with

```
phonegap build ios
```

The first issue: I got this error

```
Build Error
===========
ld: '/Users/user000516/Downloads/my-app - ioS/platforms/ios/samplePush/Plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/GCM/Libraries/libGGLCloudMessaging.a(GGLContext+CloudMessaging.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Which means the push plugin could not compile with bitcode enabled. I disabled bitcode in xCode and the project built successfully. I am not sure if this was the reason the build from Phonegap Build was failing.

The second issue: The other thing I did from XCode was to got the Capabilities tab and enable the Push Notification capability.

After these changes the code worked as expected.

Hope this helps someone

Comment: Hi! I'm having the same problem. I tried to disable bitcode in my project.pbxproj file, but is not working yet. Do you have another solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi eliangela are you also using the phonegap push plugin . What error are you getting ?

Comment: Yes. I'm using Phonegap Push Plugin. But I'm not having any error :(
My iPhone isn't registering and doesn't return the Token

Answer (score 0):

NOT SURE IF I SHOULD EDIT MY QUESTION OR RATHER PROVIDE SOLUTION AS ANSWER.

SOLVED

As an update. It turns out that there was nothing wrong with the code. There were two main issues.

I eventually borrowed a mac(from macincloud) and built the project with

```
phonegap build ios
```

The first issue: I got this error

## Build Error

```
ld: '/Users/user000516/Downloads/my-app -          ioS/platforms/ios/samplePush/Plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/GCM/Libraries/libGGLCloudMessaging.a(GGLContext+CloudMessaging.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode   for this target. for architecture arm64
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Which means the push plugin could not compile with bitcode enabled. I disabled bitcode in xCode and the project built successfully. I am not sure if this was the reason the build from Phonegap Build was failing.

The second issue: The other thing I did from XCode was to got the Capabilities tab and enable the Push Notification capability.

After these changes the code worked as expected.

Hope this helps someone